# LINQ FindAll returning same item twice

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq

I have a table in my database with three columns and two rows:

The columns are: `Id`, `PersonId` and `ListName`

The values in the first row are: `1, 1, 'ListOne'`

The values in the second row are: `2, 1, 'ListTwo'`

When I try to select these items I'm using LINQ:

```
var values = dbContext.Table.FindAll().ToList();
```

The object values has 2 items, just like the table itself. The problem is that it's selecting the first row twice and ignoring the second row, instead of selecting each row just once.

What can I do to retrieve these values from my table correctly?

I've already tried different LINQ methods and they all returned the same thing.

Comment: Don't use FindAll if you aren't going to specify a filter clause within it. Use .All() instead.

Comment: or just `dbContext.Table.ToList();`. Btw.: is there a `FindAll` overload with no parameters?

Comment: Isn't `FindAll` even unnecessary in this case? Calling `ToList()` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The error was in my model class. I was overriding the Id with the PersonId value.